# Show that the boolean formulas $[(p ∧ ¬q) ∨ q] ∧ [(¬q ∧ p) ∨ r] and (p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (r ∧ q)$ are equivalent.

Tags: propositional-calculus

So far I got this:

$[(p ∧ ¬q) ∨ q] ∧ [(¬q ∧ p) ∨ r]$:

- $p∧ T ∧ [(¬q∧p) ∨ r]$
- $p∧ [(p∧¬q) ∨ r]$
- $p \lor r$

$(p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (r ∧ q):$

- $(p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (q ∧ r)$
- $(p ∧( ¬q ∨ q)∧ r$
- $p ∧ T ∧ r$
- $p ∧ r$

Comment: By commutativity of $\land$, your first formula is equivalent to $[(p\land\neg q)\lor q]\land[(p\land\neg q)\lor r]$ and your second formula is equivalent to $(p\land\neg q)\lor(q\land r)$. And these are equivalent by the distributive law.

Comment: can you please explain a little more on how  [(p ∧ ¬q) ∨ q] ∧ [(¬q ∧ p) ∨ r] =(p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (r ∧ q)

Comment: [(p∧¬q) V q ] ∧(p∧¬q) v r ] under first formula?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see a way to explain more. My comment already broke the argument into three steps, each applying only one of the laws of propositional logic --- two uses of the commutative law of $\land$ and one use of the distributive law. I see no way to break it down any further.

Comment: Thank you! its making a lot more sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing this right. You can't just move parentheses around like you do.

For example, for the first one, you go from $(p \land \neg q) \lor q$ to $p \land \top$, but that must mean you went from $(p \land \neg q) \lor q$ to $p \land (\neg q \lor q)$ .... which is not right:

In general, $(p \land q) \lor r$ is *not* equivalent to $p \land (q \lor r)$

You are similarly moving parentheses for the second expression in a way that is not allowed. Think about it: what if this was an algebraic expression using numbers? It would be like going from $(3 + 4) \cdot (5+6)$ to $3 + 4 \cdot 5 + 6$ ... that's clearly not something you can do!

Comment: yea that makes sense, im just not sure where to begin.

Comment: @DerekLong see Andreas' comment !